Please Review my PCB stackup
I am developing an AM6442 SOM.
This is PCB layer stackup

This my layer assignments:

L1: Signals - Low Speed (UART, QEP, PWM, DeltaSigma ADC, GPIO, JTAG)
L2: Ground Plane
L3: Signals - HighSpeed Speed (LPDDR4, RGMII, MMCSD)
L4: Power Plane
L5: Power Plane
L6: Signals - HighSpeed Speed (LPDDR4, RGMII, MMCSD)
L7: Ground Plane
L8: Signals - Low Speed (UART, QEP, PWM, DeltaSigma ADC, GPIO, JTAG)

This is first attempt designing such highspeed signals.
My questions w.r.t the above PCB stackup:

Is having a common ground plane assingment for 2 signal layers a good idea?
Is having high speed signals like LPDDR4 in between Ground and Power plane a good idea.
Should I or should I not use pour on L3/L6 if yes which pour? Ground? Power? or should i chose any from ground or power according to routing convenience?


I don't have the required experience to review the PCB stackup, but TI provide Application Note High-Speed Interface Layout Guidelines which is linked from the Application Note Hardware Design Guide for AM6442, AM6422, M6412 and AM2434 Processors. Do those TI documents help?

The TI doc has a recommendation for 8 layer stackup, but it's not very specific/detailed, and TI themselves don't seem to be following their recommendation in their development boards. Their development boards use much more safer stackup having 4 ground planes and 2 power planes for a 10 layer stackup.

It would be good if you can put a table up of the layers with impedance and thickness as well as if you'll run differential and single ended signals.

There are many factors to balance and no one method that works best for all designs.  I quickly address your Qs followed by hopefully relevant advice. When I say "controlled impedance traces", that what is used for routing the "high-speed signal" traces. High-speed signals longer than critical length become transmission lines and should be routed as controlled impedance traces.

Is having a common ground plane assignment for 2 signal layers a good idea?   YES
Is having high speed signals like LPDDR4 in between Ground and Power plane a good idea.  Yes, but the power plane must be continuous under controlled impedance traces (i.e. controlled impedance traces never cross a gap/split/cut  in adjacent power or ground layer), AND there should be bypass caps nearby at the trace endpoints connected to the power and ground planes, which is typically the case anyway between a processor and memory device which are surrounded by bypass caps.
Should I or should I not use pour on L3/L6 if yes which pour? Ground? Power? or should I chose any from ground or power according to routing convenience? Generally do not add opportunistic fills (i.e. pours) on inner signal layers, but PCB manufacturer will often request to add "copper thieving" to these layers which can be unconnected copper with good clearance from traces to improve etching
(my addition) Should the outer layers (L1/L8) be avoided for high-speed (i.e., controlled impedance) signal traces?  When there is continuous/un-interrupted adjacent ground plane on L2/L7, then micro-strip routing works fine for controlled impedance traces on outer layers and does not need to be avoided.  If L2/L7 plane has cuts or splits or slots, then L1/L8 controlled-impedance (high-speed) traces MUST avoid passing over such locations, as the disruption in return path can cause signal integrity and EMI problems.

8-layer stackups are usually variants of two basic schemes below (your example is variant of scheme A), with many small variations possible such as swapping power/ground assignments.
Schema A:  alternating signal/plane layers,  S--G--S--G--P--S--G/P--S

components, SMT breakout, signals with controlled impedance
ground return plane
signals with controlled impedance, small-signal analog or RF signals
ground return plane (or could be power if not split near L3 controlled impedance)
split power fills (or could be ground if L4 is solid power)
signals, lower speed (avoid controlled impedance due to layer 5 splits)
ground return plane and/or power fills
fewer components, SMT breakout, signals with controlled impedance only over continuous L7 ground fills/planes

Scheme B: two adjacent signal layers between planes, G--S--S--G--P--S--S/P--G

components, SMT breakout, ground fills
micro-via breakout, signals with controlled impedance only under L1 ground fills
micro-via breakout, signals with controlled impedance only under L1 ground fills, local power fills
ground return plane
split power fills
signals, lower speed (avoid controlled impedance due to layer 5 splits)
signals, power fills if needed
components, SMT breakout, ground fills

Today, designs often have so many different critical power domains that an entire layer devoted to a specific power net (e.g. +3.3v) would require too many power layers.  So the power layers are frequently split between multiple large power fills sharing a layer or two, and then stategically interlaced under the loads, expanding whenever possible to use as much area as available.
Scheme A (vs. Scheme B) is generally more robust for good impedance control and flexibility of routing direction (horizontal/vertical) shifting within same layer. At completion of routing, outer layers are often filled with ground with large trace-to-fill spacing, and then ground stitching vias added to tie together outer copper.
Comparing your PCB stackup proposal with my generic Scheme A, main difference is rather than two solid power planes (L4,L5), Scheme A proposes additional ground plane (L4) and split power plane (L5).  Scheme A suggests L6 should avoid controlled impedance traces that would reference that split power L5 because of difficulty to avoid routing across the L5 gaps at the splits, but if the L5 plane is solid (single power) this is not an issue.
Another difference is having control impedance traces reference only ground planes or reference power and ground planes. In your proposed PCB stackup, which references both power planes and ground planes, if there is a controlled impedance trace that changes from L1/L8 to L3/L6 or from L3 to L6, the return current switches from ground layer only (L2 or L7) to being split between ground (L2/L7) and/or different power (L4/L5) layers.  For this portion of the return current to move easily between ground and power layers requires a nearby bypass cap connecting these layers. If the signal layer transition via location is far from the endpoint components, it could also be far from where the bypass caps are normally placed.  So, the guidance is to either add additional small bypass caps at these locations (e.g., 100pF in smallest package), or try to avoid such layer changes when far from endpoint components.  If the traces are busses between components and the breakout layer changes can be made near the endpoint components where the bypass caps are already nearby, that is a good strategy which avoids this problem.  In scheme A, similar effect happens when controlled impedance traces changes between L1, L3, and L8, which all reference only ground planes but still the return current needs to change between these ground layers.  Now the equivalent guidance is to connect these ground layers with a nearby ground via close to the signal via.  A ground stitching via is easier/quicker to add than a bypass cap and two vias. The significance of disrupted split return current issue depends on many factors (especially trace length), and I've often seen this guideline violated without any causing problems. If you have access to post-routing Signal Integrity TDR simulations, that can help find places where this level of routing details would cause problems or could be improved.
So, one must evaluate which variation of multiple power planes vs split power plane works best looking at the particular design details. The tradeoff is added complexity of designing/routing a split power plane to gain an extra ground plane, which then makes controlled impedance routing more robust/easier, compared against your proposed variant with additional solid power plane, which would make power routing easier, but could also require adding some extra power bypass caps at critical controlled impedance layer transition locations. If the different power domain pins are all in overlapping areas without obvious partitioning pattern, perhaps more power planes is better. If the power pins tend to cluster together on power domains, like FPGA power banks going to different peripherals at single voltage, then the split single power layer could better.
Scheme B strategy is probably most useful for thinner PCBs with high-density BGA-to-BGA routing that include the more expensive blind and/or buried micro vias.  When micro vias are needed for small pin-pitch BGA breakout, sometimes signals must breakout on L2 and L3 (unavoidable) and when going between a processor and nearby memory IC, keeping the signals there end-to-end may be easier. layer 2-to-3 micro vias also allows lots of flexibility in controlled impedance routing without long thru-via stubs that also block other layers.
When two signal layers are adjacent in scheme B, offset stripline traces are  used for controlled impedance, but there are also so many more ways to mess up...  Need to avoid coupling of parallel routes on adjacent layers, so assign one vertical and one horizontal and stager traces in breakout regions. Return paths (i.e. mirror current on reference layers) for stripline traces need to be continuous above and below trace, so keeping controlled impedance between two ground layers is easier than between ground and split power.  If a controlled impedance trace changes references between power and ground layers, there should be a small bypass cap (high-frequency short) near the signal via to complete the return path.  Also if a component connects to controlled impedance traces routed on inner layers there must be ground vias to inner ground layers near where the traces connect to inner layers, i.e. do not just use the outer ground fill as the only connection to component ground pins without adding nearby ground vias to connect with inner ground layers.
And last bit of advice, always have your primary PCB manufacturer review or help define the PCB stackup overall thickness, copper thicknesses per layer, dielectric thicknesses between layers, via sizes, and the resulting controlled impedance trace widths/spacings needed on each layer to achieve target impedances at start of PCB layout to avoid specifying something they can not build. I suspect you already did this, as your stackup included all the prepeg vs. core type and thickness details that only PCB manufactures will provide.
